# Failed to find record with ID: 10071 with database picker

Tags: sql, jira, scriptrunner-for-jira

I am using a database picker custom field to retrieve the projects that I am using in Jira. The problem is that I run into many errors as shown below:

Failed to find record with ID: 10071
Failed to find record with ID: 10070
Failed to find record with ID: 10073

[image]

The list is not completely though, I am able to retrieve some items in the drop down list. Anyone knows how to fix these errors?
I am using this code as Retrieval/validation SQL:

```
select distinct code, code + ' [' + name + ']' as Product
from iTrac_products_projects
where code =?
```

I am using this code as the search SQL:

```
select code,  code + ' [' + name + ']'  as Product
from iTrac_products_projects
where lower(code) like lower(?) or lower(code) like '%'
```

Comment: Is Groovy involved? (asking because of the tag)

Comment: yes, atlassian products are based on groovy

Comment: @MounaHammoudi There's no groovy code in your question... Better to remove groovy tag

Comment: removed it, do you know what the issue is?